# How to add number with sankey's node representing the count in geom_sankey?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a sankey plot using [geom_sankey](https://github.com/davidsjoberg/ggsankey) with the following code:

here is my sample dataset:

```
df_all <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 71018L, 71019L, 71020L, 71021L, 71022L, 71023L, 71024L, 
71025L, 71026L, 71027L, 71028L, 71029L, 71030L, 71031L, 71032L, 
71033L, 71034L, 71035L, 71036L, 71037L, 71038L, 71039L, 71040L, 
71041L, 71042L, 71043L, 71044L, 71045L, 71046L, 71047L, 71048L, 
71049L, 71050L, 71051L, 71052L, 71053L, 71054L, 71055L, 71056L, 
71057L, 71058L, 71059L, 71060L, 71061L, 71062L, 71063L, 71064L, 
71065L, 71066L, 71067L, 71068L, 146432L, 146433L, 146434L, 146435L, 
146436L, 146437L, 146438L, 146439L, 146440L, 146441L, 146442L, 
146443L, 146444L, 146445L, 146446L, 146447L, 146448L, 146449L, 
146450L, 146451L, 146452L, 146453L, 146454L, 146455L, 146456L, 
146457L, 146458L, 146459L, 146460L, 146461L, 146462L, 146463L, 
146464L, 146465L, 146466L, 146467L, 146468L, 146469L, 146470L, 
146471L, 146472L, 146473L, 146474L, 146475L, 146476L, 146477L, 
146478L, 146479L, 146480L, 146481L, 146482L), author_id = c(17876844, 
970337201979568128, 2699654564, 2222233730, 32446456, 1145622134, 
981654463, 1325187065856864256, 550294414, 809037571, 369541315, 
18425738, 300449911, 110700737, 2153712019, 27317875, 4363483287, 
1286750539368325120, 968008274003005440, 2351827785, 130344472, 
188112524, 1979360274, 4363483287, 4363483287, 1471982637514477568, 
720364350, 1264433760, 1264433760, 817951317880619008, 1529390650940071936, 
1520616040207577088, 1349678580029034496, 300320695, 58658349, 
1388852765271609344, 2458525400, 1464391721819979776, 148033625, 
1085909438463123456, 94462378, 463162890, 10634942, 81134013, 
103978163, 1493357535457431552, 3157965788, 56570330, 1349678580029034496, 
3012270059, 300320695, 1143773466, 1419484955239985152, 282134662, 
36553959, 1091434038554955776, 1091434038554955776, 1091434038554955776, 
36553959, 1091434038554955776, 36553959, 36553959, 1491776087684104192, 
1491776087684104192, 36553959, 36553959, 1091434038554955776, 
1091434038554955776, 58044082, 36553959, 1091434038554955776, 
36553959, 40591485, 1091434038554955776, 2690676049, 394821583, 
1329860301823512576, 1527698277608857600, 1489464521949392896, 
1136175294589677568, 47915480, 21466812, 21466812, 21466812, 
21466812, 21466812, 21466812, 21466812, 87360635, 1508764271005642752, 
760398678410534912, 255406949, 1070877954681389056, 1087975080729165824, 
478858179, 1349678580029034496, 951200196150480896, 1445912951597195264, 
80857328, 742798982661935104, 1523820481584852992, 300320695, 
16846753, 1505615658217717760, 15835430, 1539528058444472320, 
73267618, 912466868627111936, 32446456, 32525008, 1064214431423442944, 
257581957, 318019133, 318019133, 293659365, 82350646, 117955349, 
1465427491879895040, 856727453502517248, 1497989635263250432, 
149176270, 2198146752, 856378734, 2760427748, 1537106957949100032, 
2786350780, 2290577364, 1482071521514430464, 1122896701239504896,
1505615658217717760, 849372521585573888, 1420899433848262656, 
2904715406, 2288347138, 27548337, 1408506768, 1398866593237508096, 
1132044818060926976, 15197548, 1276178452559859712, 1327327899494453248, 
1456306454307160064, 774814141420675072, 23498963, 884109059242250240, 
1527698277608857600, 3765361455, 1410549924710715392, 57747779, 
300320695, 122803897, 38011168), Title = c("1 A", "1 A", 
"1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", 
"1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", 
"1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", 
"1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", 
"1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", 
"1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", 
"1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", 
"1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", "1 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "2 A", 
"2 A", "2 A", "2 A", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", 
"3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B",
"3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", 
"3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", 
"3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", 
"3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", 
"3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", 
"3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", 
"3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B", "3 B"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
71018L, 71019L, 71020L, 71021L, 71022L, 71023L, 71024L, 71025L, 
71026L, 71027L, 71028L, 71029L, 71030L, 71031L, 71032L, 71033L, 
71034L, 71035L, 71036L, 71037L, 71038L, 71039L, 71040L, 71041L, 
71042L, 71043L, 71044L, 71045L, 71046L, 71047L, 71048L, 71049L, 
71050L, 71051L, 71052L, 71053L, 71054L, 71055L, 71056L, 71057L, 
71058L, 71059L, 71060L, 71061L, 71062L, 71063L, 71064L, 71065L, 
71066L, 71067L, 71068L, 146432L, 146433L, 146434L, 146435L, 146436L, 
146437L, 146438L, 146439L, 146440L, 146441L, 146442L, 146443L, 
146444L, 146445L, 146446L, 146447L, 146448L, 146449L, 146450L, 
146451L, 146452L, 146453L, 146454L, 146455L, 146456L, 146457L, 
146458L, 146459L, 146460L, 146461L, 146462L, 146463L, 146464L, 
146465L, 146466L, 146467L, 146468L, 146469L, 146470L, 146471L, 
146472L, 146473L, 146474L, 146475L, 146476L, 146477L, 146478L, 
146479L, 146480L, 146481L, 146482L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
#df_all is my dataset with two columns, "user_id" and "category" which ranges from A-H, it has  more than 200K rows. Each category has number 1/2/3 in the beginning which I will use to transform it into three columns.

#Transforming df_all
df_final <- mutate(df_all, step=as.numeric(str_sub(Title, end=1))) %>%
  spread(step, Title, sep='_') %>%
  group_by(author_id) %>%
  summarise('June' = sort(unique(step_1))[1],
            'July' = sort(unique(step_2))[1],
            'August' = sort(unique(step_3))[1])

#removing numbers from category
df_final$'June' <- gsub(".* ", "", df_final$'June')
df_final$'July' <- gsub(".* ", "", df_final$'July')
df_final$'August' <- gsub(".* ", "", df_final$'August')

df_final %>% 
  make_long('June', 'July', 'August') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node, label = node, fill = factor(node)))+
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.75, node.color = FALSE) +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 16)+
  labs(title = " ",
       x = 'Month',
       fill="")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size=13, hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_text(size = 11), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.text=element_text(size=11),
        axis.title=element_text(size=11),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=11),
        plot.margin = unit(c(-12, -1, 0, -1), "cm"))+
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.5)),legend.position = 'bottom')+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.5)))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow = 1))+
  scale_fill_discrete(na.value="white")
```

It gives me the following output:

[image]

My question is, is there any way we can indicate the number with the nodes (bars) to represent its count. It will much more sense. For example, if we can show the count against Red bar in each month, it will help us understand the change.  Any guidance please?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am sharing the sample data, It would not produce the plot I shared above, but something else that would still require the task explained :)